# How to pass several parameters through curl in `get` request?

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework, request

I execute a request of this kind:
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/landing?param1=1&param2=2`
As a result, I get only the first parameter. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must put the argument within quotes (double or single, depending on what you want and on what platform you use) so that the shell doesn't interpret the `&` letter.

Like this:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/landing?param1=1&param2=2"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass several parameters through curl in `get` request, the URL used in the curl get call **must be within double-quotes**.

Please Note: **you need to pass the URL in double-quotes when using several parameters, however this is not the case when there is a single parameter**.

Below are the reasons why :

1. If you see your CURL command, you will notice that you are using `&` to pass multiple values to your request parameters in this GET call/request.

`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/landing?param1=1&param2=2`

2. In the Linux/Unix environment, `&` has a pre-defined interpretation. It is used to run any command in the background. So if `&` is present after any text, then the  text is interpreted as a command and & means to run this command in the background.
3. Any text after `&` is treated as a new command. So your above Curl get request is interpreted by Linux as 2 separate commands:
   i. `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/landing?param1=1&`
   ii. `param2=2`

**Solution** : The solution to avoid this interpretation by Unix/Linux is to surround your url with double quotes `"`

`curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/landing?param1=1&param2=2"`

This will help you pass multiple parameter values to your curl get request.